# What wire do I need

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm wiring up 2 camper spots and need to know what wire I need to run from the main power pole to a sub panel to run a 30amp and 50 amp camper. It's 100ft distance from power pole to where my sub panel is. Wire will be buried.

Comment: Are you running this as *direct burial*, or as *underground conduit*?

Comment: for some reason I thought it said 2ea 50 amp sites, I would install 2 50’s and never have to worry about it, but a 30 amp site only requires 3600va  and the derate of .9 would still be allowed dropping the feeder size to 53.5 amps @ 100’  coper #8, aluminum #4 so not really that big a difference and with the larger feeder you would never have to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

For RV “parks” with 2 sites code allows a 90% demand factor each 50 amp site is required to have 9600va 2x9600= 19200 / 240= 80
 80x .9 = 72 amps. I would run #3 copper or #2 aluminum to your pedestals

based on south wires voltage drop wire size calculator using 72 amps 100’ and a 3 or 5% voltage drop they both recommend the same, a single feeder to the 2 pedestals.

For pedestals there are a couple of different ones out there I would recommend a 120/240 with all 3 outlets 50 amp 240, 30 amp 120 and a 20amp GFCI receptacle in a 3r enclosure a surface mounted model with breakers can be found online for ~120.00 From online RV places  , or at amazon for 149 one day shipping, these come with breakers and are what you find at RV parks. If you want to get fancy add pedestal to your search these cost more but do not require the 4x4 post.

Comment: Well done with the "2 campsites" rule!